# Information in bank statement when using remittance services

Tags: payment

My question refers to a scenario when we send or receive payments using a money transfer service like Wise (aka TransferWise), XE, among others.

What appears in the bank statement? Can the recipient see the name of the actual sender and not the name of the remittance company? Are senders limited to sending information to the recipient in the payment reference?

Comment: FWIW, when I make a purchase or get a payment with PayPal, I don't see the other side's identity, which is actually annoying to me when I want to reconcile and can't tell what the transaction was for.  But I suspect that in general it will depend on the provider.

Comment: I always check this sort of charge against my own records and/or those of the payment service, since not all of the data reaches the bank.

Answer (score 1):

I just checked one of my Wise to Bank Of America transfers and there is little information

```
<my name> DES:WISE ID:XXXXX5904
INDN: <my name> CO ID:XXXXX33521 IAT
PMT INFO: WEB XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX000 FOR
MORE INFORMATION CONTACT CUSTOMER
SERVICE
```

So you see the sender's name but the account numbers are partially obscured and there is no other usable information.

I have no idea how much of this is up to Wise or up to BoA.